# unable to serve static vuejs files on express

Tags: vue.js, express

Here is my express code:

```
const express = require('express');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const path = require('path');

// create the express app
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

app.use("/",serveStatic ( path.join (__dirname, '/dist') ) );
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist23')));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("listening on "+port)
});
```

The above code only works for the folder `/dist`. But when I go to `/static`, it shows a blank page and this error in the console:
[image]

If I put the js files from `/dist23` into `/dist`, then `/static` works and shows me the application. Its almost like it is looking for files inside `/dist` and not `/dist23`. How do I fix it?

Both apps were built using `vue-2.6.11`. Both directories have files built/bundled for production.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the content type while serving your static files.

```
app.get('/index.html', (req, res) => {
   res.set('content-type', 'text/plain').sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist/') })
});
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.set('content-type', 'text/plain').sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'public/dist/') })
});
```